# CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Group.Title'

Tags: c#, uwp, json.net

I'm having a problem with my UWP app and creating a favorites page which allows the user to reorder and save the data on the page. i'm getting the same error on two occasions

> CS0120    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Group.Title'
>
> CS0120    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Group.Items'

could anyone explain to me why this is happening, 
thanks.

CS File

---

```
using App1.Common;
using App1.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Data.Json;


namespace App1
{

public sealed partial class test : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemData> Items { get; set; }

    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new 
    ObservableDictionary();
    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private RootObject jsonLines;
    private StorageFile fileFavourites;
    private Dictionary<string, ItemData> ItemData = new Dictionary<string, 
    ItemData>();


    public test()
    {
    loadJson();
    getFavoritesFile();

    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    }

    void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new 
        page
        // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
        var itemId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), itemId);
    }

    private void setupObservableCollection()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemData>(ItemData.Values);
            itemGridView.ItemsSource = Items;
        }

        private async void loadJson()
        {
            var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new 
            Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json"));
            var lines = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            jsonLines = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(lines);
            feedItems();
        }

        private async void getFavoritesFile()
        {
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = 
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            fileFavourites = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Fav.txt");
        }

        private async void feedItems()
        {
            if (await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(fileFavourites) != "")
            {
                foreach (var line in await 
                FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(fileFavourites))
                {
                    foreach (var Group in jsonLines.Groups)
                    {
                    foreach (var Item in Group.Items)
                    {
                        if (Item.UniqueId == line)
                        {
                            var storage = new ItemData()
                            {
                                Title = Item.Title,
                                UniqueID = Item.UniqueId,
                                ImagePath = Item.ImagePath,
                                Group = Group.Title
                            };
                            ItemData.Add(storage.UniqueID, storage);
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            else
            {//if favourites file is empty, use?
            foreach (var Group in jsonLines.Groups) ;
            {
                foreach (var Item in Group.Items)
                {
                    var storage = new ItemData()
                    {
                        Title = Item.Title,
                        UniqueID = Item.UniqueId,
                        ImagePath = Item.ImagePath,
                        Group = Group.Title
                    };
                    ItemData.Add(storage.UniqueID, storage);
                    await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(fileFavourites, 
                    Item.UniqueId + "\r\n");
                }
            }
        }


        setupObservableCollection();
        }


        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }

        #region NavigationHelper loader

        public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
        {
            get { return this.navigationHelper; }
        }

        private async void MessageBox(string Message)
        {
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(Message);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }

        private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, 
        LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
            var sampleDataGroups = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupsAsync();
            this.defaultViewModel["Groups"] = sampleDataGroups;
        }

        #endregion NavigationHelper loader

        #region NavigationHelper registration

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        #endregion NavigationHelper registration
    }

    public class ItemData
    {
        public string UniqueID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }

}
```

---

RootObject File

```
using App1.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App1
{

public class Item
{
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}  
}
```

Comment: Another issue you will face is that you try to set the value of a foreach iteration variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occures in your `foreach` loop. Actually, there are two problems:

1. You use `Group` as iteration variable, which is possible, but leads to confusion with the class name `Group`.
2. When instantiating `new ItemData`, you suddenly use `Group.Title` instead of `Item.Title`

So a corrected version of the loop could look like this:

```
foreach (var group in jsonLines.Groups) ;
{
    foreach (var item in group.Items)
    {
        var storage = new ItemData()
        {
            Title = item.Title,
            UniqueID = item.UniqueId,
            ImagePath = item.ImagePath,
            Group = item.Title
         };
         ItemData.Add(storage.UniqueID, storage);
         await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(fileFavourites, 
                Item.UniqueId + "\r\n");
     }
 }
```

I changed the loop variable `Group` to the lower-case `group`. And I changed the second loop variable `Item` also to lower-case, which is not necessary in your case, but better complies with [C# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines).

Comment: hi this fixes everything except that i still get the error on 'group.items'

Comment: @Chuggingtonss Did you note that it has to be `group.Items`, not `Group.Items`? Mind the casing.

Comment: @Chuggingtonss And I just saw that you have a second loop with the same problems. I think my explanation should help you to fix that loop, too :)

Comment: seemed to have worked had stupidly put a comma after the first foreach statement thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your foreach you should use other names instead of Group, because it conflicts with the class's name. A lowercase group would work.